# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Tags: android

Não consigo revolver erro:
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_options_user"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView (Erro Nessa linha)
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_options_user2"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_options_user_drawer" />
```

Comment: Douglas, consegue colocar o stacktrace inteiro na pergunta? As vezes é algum erro ao inflar as demais `Views` do `NavigationView`. A princípio não vejo nenhum erro nesse trecho de layout.

Comment: consegui resolver problema, era um xml que estava dando erro.